# What is the connection url for to SyBase database file using jdbc?

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, sybase

I am trying to connect to a Sybase database **file**. I downloaded the SybDriver and it registers succesfully with `DriverManager.registerDriver`, but I don't know how to connect to a local database file. There is not much documentation of that out there (or I didn't find it). I am trying to connect with the code snippet below but I get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JZ003: Incorrect URL format. URL: 
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source) ~[jconn-4_RELEASE.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.handleSQLE(Unknown Source) ~[jconn-4_RELEASE.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.a(Unknown Source) ~[jconn-4_RELEASE.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.handleHAFailover(Unknown Source) ~[jconn-4_RELEASE.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[jconn-4_RELEASE.jar:na]
```

```
String url = "jdbc:sybase:Tds:/C/myfolder/sybase.db:5000";
String username = "admin";
String password = "pwd";

DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver)Class.forName( "com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver" ).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance() );
Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

There is probably a very specific format for trying to connect to local files but I can't find it.

Comment: Why do you think the driver would be capable of connecting to a file? As far as I'm aware - I could be wrong - you always need to connect to a Sybase server.

Comment: The people at the company I work for think this is possible. I'm not saying it has to be done like above. I just want to be able to read the database with a java program. I am obviously open for suggestions.

Comment: I have made it work by using the db file to set up a sybase server locally. Then connecting to localhost with port 2638 with connection url format and driver I described above. Not an ideal solution since we want this to run in the cloud as well.

Comment: Then you should probably switch to a database system that does support this (i.e. the database engine is either embedded or fully written in Java).

Comment: I'm doing a migration from that DB to another but similar business model  (which has a more orthodox database) so connecting to that one is a prerequisite ;)